# How to remove ViewState and EventValidation data in ASP.NET Control render to string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm using the following method to render a user control to a string:

```
Page pageHolder = new Page();
pageHolder.EnableViewState = false;

UserControl viewControl = (UserControl)pageHolder.LoadControl(path);
viewControl.EnableViewState = false;

System.Type viewControlType = viewControl.GetType();
HtmlForm tempForm = new HtmlForm();
tempForm.EnableViewState = false;

tempForm.Controls.Add(viewControl);
pageHolder.Controls.Add(tempForm);

StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(pageHolder, output, false);

string content = output.ToString();
```

However, in the output, there are *sometimes* hidden fields with `__EVENTVALIDTION` and `__VIEWSTATE` info as well as JavaScript to enable PostBack.

Is there a way to completely disable all WebForms/ViewState related code from being generated for the control I'm trying to render? Setting `EnableViewState` to false and setting the `EnabledViewState="false"` in the `.ascx` file doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try

```
<pages enableViewState="false" enableEventValidation="false">
...
</pages>
```

On your web.config?

I am not sure it's a good idea in general, but I assume you know what you are doing.

Comment: Isn't this for the whole application though?

Comment: @JamesJohnson Yes, isn't that what he wants? He said: `Is there a way to completely disable all WebForms/ViewState related code from being generated? Setting EnableViewState to false doesn't seem to work.`

Comment: I got the impression that OP just wanted to disable it for a page or a control... you could be right though...

Comment: @Icarus - James is right, I meant for the specific user control. I updated my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `EnableViewState="false"` in the directive of the user control. As for disabling event validation, I believe you can only do that through the web.config or page directive.

Comment: I don't think you can get rid of the hidden field altogether. I think you can just control what gets saved to ViewState. Have you considered parsing it out after getting the string?

Comment: I'm currently parsing it out. However, I would rather not do that as I have a bunch of conditionals checking if values exist or not.